# Adding labels dynamically without specifying location in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am trying to learn VB.net and I have encountered a problem. I am trying to add labels dynamically to a panel/textbox/groupbox. I noticed that while creating a dynamic label, I would have to specify the **location** property. I was a bit surprised by this - why would I have to manage the exact location of where the new label will be created? Why not have a layout manager which would automatically take care of this? Anyway, I couldn't find a way to do doing this, but I found an example which advocated usage of textbox to add labels dynamically. But, I am only seeing one label being displayed no matter what in the textbox. (when I debugged, I noticed that more labels were added to the controls object, but display did not reflect accordingly)

Here's what it looks like

[image: only one label!]

Here's the code I am using

```
Private Sub AddTagCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addTagCombo.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim selectedTag = addTagCombo.Text
        If Not IsDuplicateTag(selectedTag) Then
            Dim label As Label = New Label
            label.Text = selectedTag
            label.Name = selectedTag
            label.AutoSize = True
            label.Top = 10
            label.Left = 10
            tagsBox.Controls.Add(label)
        End If
    End Sub
```

How do I add dynamic labels without worrying about the location of where they will be placed inside another container?

Comment: You are no longer using a mouse to drop the label on the form from the toolbox.  So you no longer have the designer set the Location property for you and you have to do it yourself.  Right now you are putting them all on top of each other, so you can only see the last one you added.  A FlowLayoutPanel tends to be useful to arrange them automagically.  Or other controls that can display multiple strings, like ComboBox, DomainUpDown, ListBox, ListView, TreeView, DataGridView.  Try them all.

Comment: I am a bit confused about flowlayoutpanel. Do  you see anything wrong with my code? Why would it not show more than one control?

Comment: I have a very hard time understanding what you don't understand.  What did you *expect* to happen when you stack labels on top of each other?  How do you read the title printed on the front of a book that is on the bottom of a stack of books?

Comment: @HansPassant coming from Java world, not having to specify location for dynamic components and layout managers taking care of many things for you - so understandably I was confused. May be my question was dumb - but there is no general guideline here that says you cannot ask a dumb question. If that ticks you off, I am sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks ok and generates labels successfully. But it puts your new labels above each other as their locations are identical.

All what you need to chabge the location of each new label. For example, increment lebel.Top for each new labels.

Here a suggestion how to to that:

```
'Add a variable to increment top location
Dim TopFactor As Integer = 1

Private Sub AddTagCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addTagCombo.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim selectedTag = addTagCombo.Text
    If Not IsDuplicateTag(selectedTag) Then
        Dim label As Label = New Label
        label.Text = selectedTag
        label.Name = selectedTag
        label.AutoSize = True
        label.Top = 10 * TopFactor
        label.Left = 10
        tagsBox.Controls.Add(label)

 'Increment TopFactor
  TopFactor +=1
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, the first label will be on location (10,10), the second will be on location (20, 10) .. and so on.

Hope this solve your isssue.

Comment: But I want to lay them in rows, and once a row gets filled, I want them on the next row..

Comment: @Jay : So use a [**`FlowLayoutPanel`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx), like already suggested! -- Also, FYI, _rows_ go from top to bottom (like the answer's code does), but _**columns**_ however go from left to right.